# Wildfly 10 Final indefinitely creating ActiveMQ-client-global-threads

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, wildfly-10, jconsole

I have a `Wildfly AS` setup for JMS, I;m monitoring it with Jconsole and have noticed that before I even create a session on my `Consumer` or `Producer` the thread count is steadily increasing, I was previously using `Wildfly 9 final` for the same purpose, it's thread usage was steady even during use, but it had a memory leak which prompted me to upgrade.

In `Jconsole` I can see:

```
Thread-2(ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-3258368)
Thread-4(ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-3258368)
Thread-5(ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-3258368)
Thread-6(ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-3258368)
.
.
.
Thread-16(ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-3258368)
```

How do I solve this problem? is there a setting I can change that is causing these threads to spawn, is there any more information I can take from `Jconsole` to help me resolve this?

Comment: I have the same problem... Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:
I tried with this configuration and it doesn't work for me.
The reason is that ActiveMq Artemis uses a fixed thread pool executor and it is configured to 500 threads. It will be solved in Wildfly after somoe changes in Artemis.
You can check the status in Jira (look in the last comments):

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-2947

Forum:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268397

Workaround:

```
sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=30
```

---

Original Answer:

Have you tried setting remote connection properties?

```
 <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory"
 entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
 connectors="http-connector" use-global-pools="false"
 thread-pool-max-size="10"/>
```

Comment: This was the solution I got on the Jboss forums, I had planned to come back and answer the question, you've saved me the trouble, thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi Johntk I updated the answer after talk with the wildfly team. Regards

Comment: This solution did resolve the issues for me, I am using wildfly 10 CR4

Comment: Ok Johntk! I tried with this and I can't solve my problem... but this parameter works for me: 
sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=30

Comment: Just wanted to state that we had the same issue with Artemis chewing up our memory on Wildfly 10. We solved it by adding the `artemis thread.pool.max.size` to wildfly/bin/standalone.conf`. Inside the default `if` block checking for Java options, we added, `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=100"`

Comment: ok! @BRasmussen! JAVA_OPTS variable is a good point to set this kind of command line parameters passed to the java virtual machine during wildfly initialization, memory settings, etc. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can fine tuning the MDB for a specific use case just setting the properties `useGlobalPools` to false and `threadPoolMaxSize` according to the expected limit:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "queue/emailQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useGlobalPools", propertyValue = "false"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "threadPoolMaxSize", propertyValue = "20"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
```

If you set the connection factory properties `use-global-pools="false"` and
`thread-pool-max-size="20"` in the standalone.xml or even pass as a VM argument, you will have a global behavior applied for all MDBs, it is maybe not a good idea.