# Client-Side Thread Management ActiveMQ

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic, wildfly-10

I'm trying to setup client side thread management on a `Wildlfy 10 AS` for JMS using `ActiveMQ`, I have a  queue setup in `standalone-full.xml` `DemoQueue` currently the `AS` is creating endless threads eating up memory till eventual it crashes

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="demoQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/demoQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/demoQueue"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

I have it working with server side thread management.
I'v been trying to follow the instructions found [here](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.2.0/thread-pooling.html) so currently I'm using :

```
DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY=jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
DEFAULT_DESTINATION=java:/jms/queue/demoQueue
DEFAULT_USERNAME=mUserName
DEFAULT_PASSWORD=myPassword
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
PROVIDER_URL=http-remoting://myURL.com:8082

/** Lookup the queue object */
Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_DESTINATION"));

/** Lookup the queue connection factory */
ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY"));

try (javax.jms.Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_USERNAME"), props.getProperty("DEFAULT_PASSWORD"));

   /** Create a queue session */
   Session queueSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

   /** Create a queue consumer */
   MessageConsumer msgConsumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue)) {

   /** Set an asynchronous message listener */
   msgConsumer.setMessageListener(asyncReceiver);

   /** Set an asynchronous exception listener on the connection */
   connection.setExceptionListener(asyncReceiver);

   /** Start connection */
   connection.start();
}
```

Do I need to add the `ClientSessionFactory` configuration to my "standalone-full.xml" for  client side thread management?
I can't access the .setUseGlobalPools(falase); from the RemoteConnectionFactory.

I've tried adding:

```
ConnectionFactory myConnectionFactory = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactory(myFactory);
```

I can't seem to access the needed methods from my code.

> .useGlobalPools=false
>
> scheduledThreadPoolMaxSize=10

I was using `Wildfly 9` which implemented `HornetQ` so some of my configuration may need changing to work properly with `ActiveMQ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was showin a solution to this by a helpful user over on the `Jboss` [forums](https://developer.jboss.org/inbox?objectType=2&objectID=951320) I used server side thread management by modifying my XML configuration

```
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory"
 entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
 connectors="http-connector" use-global-pools="false"
 thread-pool-max-size="10"/>
```

Another `Stack` [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537552/wildfly-10-final-indefinitely-creating-activemq-client-global-threads) has pointed out on another question I had, that there may be an issue with this and other `Wildfly` version where this setting will not solve the problem, it did solve it for me, but there is another work around, by passing in the setting as a param during launch:

```
sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=30
```